# Magento 2 : Error While Adding Configuration Product From Listing Page

Tags: configurable-product, error, addtocart, magento2.2.2

How to add **configurable product** to cart from **product listing page**?

Normal products are added but while trying **for configurable product geeting error.**

attribute is bind after checkout url so once page is loaded getting error for page not found. But product is added to cart. Url become like: checkoout/#size=168&color=50

Comment: Can you please share the error got?

Comment: Hello Aniket please share the error.

Comment: attribute is bind after checkout url so once page is loaded getting error for page not found. But product is added to cart.                                                          
Url become like:  checkoout/#size=168&color=50